# how to add new container on button pressed?

Tags: flutter

hello i want to add a new container which contains a textediting and an image on button pressed but it doesnt not work, while on initstate a fixed container is shown
her is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:servinera_customer/Models/Issues.dart';

final _FormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


class AddIssues extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _AddIssues createState() => _AddIssues();
}

class _AddIssues extends State<AddIssues> {

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        containers.add(issue());
    }

    var issueNote = <TextEditingController>[];
    List <Issue> issues;
    var containers = <Container>[];

  //  File _image;
    var images = <File>[];
    final picker = ImagePicker();

    Future getImage() async {
        final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

        setState(() {
            if (pickedFile != null) {
                images.last = File(pickedFile.path);
            } else {
                print('No image selected.');
            }
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(elevation: 0,),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                onPressed: () {
                    // var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                    // builder: (BuildContext context) => MakeTransfer(value: _getTotalPaymentBalance())
                    //);
                    // Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                },
                label: const Text('Proceed', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18)),
             //   icon: const Icon(Icons),
            ),
            body: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: containers.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return containers[index];
                            },
                        ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: TextButton(
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            onPressed: () => {setState(() => containers.add(issue())),}
                        ),
                    )
                ],
            )
        );
    }

    Container issue(){
        var issueNoteController =  TextEditingController();
        return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                    new Flexible(
                        child: TextFormField(
                            controller: issueNoteController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                maxLines: 3,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Please describe your damaged accessories or your desired service.',
                                    contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                                    labelText: 'Your Issue'
                                ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        width: 80,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: TextButton(
                            child: images.last == null ? Icon(Icons.camera_alt) : Image.file(images.last) ,
                                onPressed: () => {
                                    getImage()
                                }
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

can anyone help..

I used some code from stackoverflow questions but it didnt work for me.
i used an array of textediting and array of file of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stripped part of your code and this works. I'm not sure if the differences in our code are what's breaking it but I've tested this in a Dart pad and it works fine. My suggestion would be to start off with this code and see if it runs. If it does, start adding things back and test it each time to see if it breaks.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AddIssues(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddIssues extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddIssues createState() => _AddIssues();
}

class _AddIssues extends State<AddIssues> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    containers.add(issue());
  }

  var issueNote = <TextEditingController>[];
  var containers = <Container>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          // var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
          // builder: (BuildContext context) => MakeTransfer(value: _getTotalPaymentBalance())
          //);
          // Navigator.of(context).push(route);
        },
        label: const Text('Proceed',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18)),
        //   icon: const Icon(Icons),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: containers.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return containers[index];
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: TextButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() => containers.add(issue()));
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container issue() {
    var issueNoteController = TextEditingController();
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          new Flexible(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: issueNoteController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: 3,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText:
                    'Please describe your damaged accessories or your desired service.',
                contentPadding:
                    new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                labelText: 'Your Issue',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```